# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n\left(1+\sqrt[2^n]{2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

Here is another infinite sum I need you help with:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n\left(1+\sqrt[2^n]{2}\right)}.$$
I was told it could be represented in terms of elementary functions and integers.

Comment: Where do you find all these problems? And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: See my comment at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389991/closed-form-for-prod-n-1-infty-sqrt2n-tanh2n And there are many problems I managed to solve myself, but I do not post them as questions at Math.SE

Comment: It probably is $-1+(\ln(2))^{-1} = 0.442695\dots$ but I'll leave it to the others for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Alright, have you ever read this thing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layla_and_Majnun

Comment: You remind me of Chris's sister and pals, somehow (that's positive). This being said, I'll wait for one of the local Ramanujans to find the answer. Oh, wait, someone already found something...

Comment: @WillJagy I haven't. Why?

Comment: Laila, just your name. There is an Iranian woman on Chat sometimes who quotes Persian poetry, I remembered this item today. No other reason.

Comment: @julien I was glad to read your message :-). These problems are really amazing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{2^{-n}}{2^{2^{-n}}-1}-\frac{2^{-(n-1)}}{2^{2^{-(n-1)}}-1}  = \frac{2^{-n}}{2^{2^{-n}}+1} $$

Thus we have a telescoping sum.  However, note that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{-n}}{2^{2^{-n}}-1} = \frac{1}{\log{2}}$$

Therefore the sum is

$$a_1-a_0 + a_2-a_1 + a_3-a_2 + \ldots + \frac{1}{\log{2}} = \frac{1}{\log{2}}- a_0$$

where

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n \left ( 2^{2^{-n}}-1\right)}$$

or

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n \left ( 1+ \sqrt[2^n]{2}\right)}= \frac{1}{\log{2}}-1$$

Comment: Do you have a manufacture for these ? :-) (or at least a table...)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: I just guessed that there was an anti-difference.  It was just a metter of expressing the summand in the right way to see how to go about it.

Comment: Hmmm... and in the case of the sum of $\cot{x}-2\cot{2 x}=\tan{x}$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389850/need-help-with-calculating-this-sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac12n-tan-frac1/389859#comment834267_389859) ? (for those who missed this nice trick)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: I have been working at math-contest-type problems for the better part of 25 years.  I have seen a lot of tricks in that time. ;-)

Comment: Nicely done, Rongordonujan.

Comment: @julien: of all the compliments I have been paid (hopefully more numerous than the insults I have been paid), that is the first time I have ever been called that.  Yet again, you are too kind.

Comment: Congratulations on getting it first (+1). Since I put some effort into my solution, I hope you don't mind if I leave it up.

Comment: @robjohn: be my guest.  I would be deluding myself if I thought that I was the only one on this site that could possibly answer this question.

Comment: @robjohn Two rats bet me :-) +1 to both the rats. Last half hour of my effort gone!

Comment: @user17762: one guy compares me with Ramanujan, another calls me a rat.  Easy come, easy go.

Comment: @RonGordon The `rats` was supposed to be a complement :).

Comment: @user17762: heh, I know, just a little dark humor on my part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Notice that
$$
\frac1{2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{2}-1)}
-\frac1{2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{2}+1)}
=\frac1{2^{n-1}(\sqrt[2^{n-1}]{2}-1)}
$$
We can rearrange this to
$$
\left(\frac1{2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{2}-1)}-1\right)
=\frac1{2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{2}+1)}
+\left(\frac1{2^{n-1}(\sqrt[2^{n-1}]{2}-1)}-1\right)
$$
and for $n=1$,
$$
\frac1{2^{n-1}(\sqrt[2^{n-1}]{2}-1)}-1=0
$$
therefore, the partial sum is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{2}+1)}
=\frac1{2^m(\sqrt[2^m]{2}-1)}-1
$$
Taking the limit as $m\to\infty$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{2}+1)}
=\frac1{\log(2)}-1
$$

Comment: Darn! I thought I would get this first because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n}-1)=\log(x)$ is one of my recent favorite limits, but Ron got it first. :-(